# Finding bad performer across the whole week

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following code giving me almost what I want.

```
stores.groupby(['Days','Regions', 'Area'])['Performance'].mean()
```

But my real aim is to get the a similar object with a Performance lower than 70 across the whole week. In other terms, stores that haven't had an average above 70 every day of the week or even for at least 3 days of the week.

Comment: I think you are missing some details about the 'week' column. Can you give a sample of the data set that you are working with to clarify your issue? Perhaps 'Days' are giving you a date?

Answer (score 1):

You might want something like:

```
s = stores.groupby(['Days','Regions', 'Area'])['Performance'].mean()
s[s<70]
```

Comment: thanks. again but this gives me all the stores as I suspected. But I want only the ones that recurring with bad performance the whole  week or at least  3 days.

Comment: We need a sample data set to help you, create some dummy data please and add it your original question.

Comment: @Herc01, I guess it can be obtained by `s[s<70].reset_index().Area.value_counts() > 2`. It gives you which `Area`s has bad performance for at least 3 days (True).

Comment: Thanks again for the pro activity. The code seems to produce a Boolean so I cannot  really see them.@bakka

Comment: @Herc01 , yes you right. from there you can use true Area to select from your original dataframe. You didnt provide sample data, I was just guessing your desired output.